# Integrating some characteristic functions

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, lebesgue-integral, characteristic-functions

How would I go about computing the following function:

$$F(x_1,x_2) = \int_0^1 \chi_{[0,1]^2}(x_1 - t, x_2-t) \ dt$$

My idea is to observe that

$$F(x_1, x_2) = \int_0^1 \chi_{[0,1]} (x_1-t) \chi_{[0,1]} (x_2-t)  dt$$

But then I'm unsure what to do afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $[x_1-1,x_1]\cap [x_2-1,x_2]$ is  an interval (or empty). (You can write down the end points of this interval by considering various cases). $F(x_1,x_2)$ is the length of this interval (or $0$ if the intersection is empty)  because the integrand is $1$ if $t$ is in this interval and $0$ otherwise.